# Explain my output

Tags: java, c#, operator-keyword

My output should be `5 30` but, the output is `5 25` I want know why it giving `5 25`

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   int i = 1, j = 5;

   do
   {
       System.out.println( i = i++ * j);
   } 
   while (i <= 10);

   System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Are you understanding `i=i++ * j` correctly?

Comment: I think you are not understanding it correctly at all.

Comment: did you debug and checked step by step what happens? debugging is the way to find those things out.

Comment: Why would you expect `5 30`?  To me, it seems obvious that it's `5 25`.  The value of `i++` is the _old_ value of `i`, not the _incremented_ value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First iteration:

```
i == 1 : i=i++ * j
            1  * 5 = 5
```

Second iteration:

```
i == 5 : i=i++ * j
            5  * 5 = 25
```

Note that the post increment operator returns the original value of the variable (prior to it being incremented).

I find it strange that you expected the correct output (5) in the first iteration, but didn't follow the same logic to get the correct output (25) in the second iteration.

Seeing your comment, you should note that the expression `i=i++ * j` is evaluated in the following order:

1. `i++` is evaluated, returning the original value of `i` (`1` in the first iteration) and incrementing `i` to `2`.
2. the multiplication is evaluated - `1 * 5`, which is equal to `5`.
3. `i` (whose value prior to the assignment was `2`) is assigned `5`.

Comment: would like to know in curious..what happens to that i++ after giving its old value for calculation.

Comment: @sudha `i++` increments `i`, but `i=i++ * j` assigns a new value to `i`, which overwrites that incremented value.

Comment: i think after 1st iteration value of i incremented by 1 means now value of i=6 (after 1st iteration completed). In 2nd iteration value like i= 6 * 5

Answer (score 0):

First run:
    i = 1 * 5
print : 5
value of i: 5

Second run:
    i = 5 * 5
print : 25

Answer (score 0):

Operation : 
`i = i++ * j` - Here it is ignoring `i++` post-increment due to assigning back to same variable, i,e. `i`.
It is effectively same as `i = i * j`

So, it is giving output `5, 25`

while, `i = ++i * j` will give output `10, 55`.

Comment: In first Iteration i= ++i + j  means i=2 * 5  : i=10 and assign the value in i now value of i is 10 , In second iteration first increment the value of i and calculate the expression like  i= 11 * 5  :i=55

Comment: Do, you mean to say `In first Iteration i= ++i * j ` in stead of `In first Iteration i= ++i + j `?  ... Rest all you have understood in good way :)